# Accessing stage properties

Tags: actionscript-3

After troubleshooting for !@#% hours, it has come to my attention that I am unable to access the stage's properties in the constructor for a class. Given a DisplayObject subclass this, for example, does not work:

```
Constructor() {
    this.width = stage.stageWidth;
}
```

The main issue here is that the object has not been added to the stage - as I understand it: since it doesn't know "where it sits" it is unable to determine the stage width. In this case it's easy to fix the issue by calling `this.width = stage.stageWidth` in response to an `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event

This method breaks down when working with a class that is never added to the stage, though - a subclass of BitmapData that contains functions for manipulating a representation of the stage, for example. As far as I know there can be only one stage associated with a given .swf... I feel like there must be SOME way to pass stage properties to a non-DisplayObject class without resorting to passing them as parameters.

Comment: without a stage, a display object wont ever have any valuable dimensions. So you could use a default value, or face the face that there are no dimensions without a stage and write code which can handle it. I already figured out all issues to this problem.

Comment: Read on - I'm not concerned with the display object! Or are you referring to the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `Stage` in your class that isn't part of display list, pass stage as argument. Pass reference on the stage to constructor of the class. Your entry point in the application is Document Class, get reference there on the stage, and pass it.

```
//Somewhere, where you have reference on the stage
var helper: SomeUtilityClass = new SomeUtilityClass(this.stage);
```

Comment: No other way, eh? If no one else provides a better solution, I'll be sure to accept this one - thanks again, Nicolas!

Comment: There are other solutions, but I don't like them. For example create static member for the stage, so it will be accessible from anywhere. But I would recommend omit `static` in the AS3 projects. It's very slow. Actually in good designed application, stage is only needed for getting size of the screen ;)

Comment: End-goal in this case is to create a utility class that represents a border on the stage, but is not a display object (it just hosts the graphics data). An odd problem, but one that is necessary for my project. Without the bounds of the stage, I have no way to create the object properly. A dilemma...

Answer (score 0):

well this could do it, by overriding a getter:

```
public class MyDisplayObject extends DisplayObject {
    //you constructor here

    public override function get width():Number {
        return (this.stage) ? this.stageWidth : <default>;
    }
}
```

This approach wont let you run in the problem of knowing the width of the stage before the object actually is added to the stage. But you should actually listen to the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event, to set the width when available (in case you want the object to always be at the same width as the stage). Additionally you could listen to the event `RESIZE` to update it properly.